# How to check if python module exists and can be imported

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am using [debug toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) with django and would like to add it to project if two conditions are true:

- `settings.DEBUG` is `True`
- module itself exists

It's not hard to do the first one

```
# adding django debug toolbar
if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    INSTALLED_APPS += 'debug_toolbar',
```

But how do I check if module exists?

I have found this solution:

```
try:
    import debug_toolbar
except ImportError:
    pass
```

But since import happens somewhere else in django, I need if/else logic to check if module exists, so I can check it in settings.py

```
def module_exists(module_name):
    # ??????

# adding django debug toolbar
if DEBUG and module_exists('debug_toolbar'):
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    INSTALLED_APPS += 'debug_toolbar',
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the same logic inside your function:

```
def module_exists(module_name):
    try:
        __import__(module_name)
    except ImportError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

There is no performance penalty to this solution because modules are imported only once.

Comment: Couldn't you use  `__import__(module_name, fromlist=[module_name])` instead of `import debug_toolbar`?

Comment: @Dan D.: Wouldn't that be equivalent to `from debug_toolbar import debug_toolbar`?  But even if it worked, what's the advantage?

Comment: no, oddly it's the same as `import debug_toolbar`; i've tested this on python 2.5.2; the advantage is that you can then use `module_exists("some_other_module")`.

Comment: @Dan D.: You are right, I'm completely ignoring the parameter to the function!  I'll fix it -- I don't need the `fromlist` argument, so I'll just omit it.

Comment: note `fromlist=` argument is required if you want `__import__` to return `email.utils` as without it'll return `email` and not `email.utils`; but this doesn't matter here as although it won't return the right module it will still raise `ImportError` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @sven, I'm not sure it's fair to say there is no performance impact... based on my timeit runs, I think `try / except` is still somewhat slower than `.get()`

Comment: @Mike: Well, what I mean is that performance is no major concern here.  I interpreted the question differently to you -- I'll comment on your answer.

Comment: I think that is a widely using but defective way. If using this way to check `a.b` module and `a.b` is exists actually, but an error importing happend in `a.b`, then the real error message will be hidden.

Comment: @TonySeek:  If there is an error while importing `a.b`, that error will be shown, unless it is an `ImportError`, in which case it will indeed be ignored.  This is *exactly* what the OP asked for, since the failing import happens somewhere in nested module imports, and so we *have to* ignore any `ImportError`.  (Moreover, it's a bit pointless to downvote without giving an alternative.)