# Python: is there a better way to skip the test module?

Tags: python

I read [How do I skip a whole Python unittest module at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487532/how-do-i-skip-a-whole-python-unittest-module-at-run-time) and this doesn't seems like a very neat way

In Java all you have to say is `@Ignore` on test class and the entire test class is ignored

Is there a better way to `skip` the entire test module or shall i just do

```
class TestMe():
  @unittest.skip
  def test_a(self):
    pass

  @unittest.skip
  def test_b(self):
    pass
  ...
```

by adding `@unittest.skip` on all the test on module

Comment: Uh... are you talking to yourself?

Comment: There was a guy, but he deleted his comment it seems ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the decorator on the class, [as per the docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures):

```
@unittest.skip("showing class skipping")
class MySkippedTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_not_run(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 4):

As per comment, the following works

```
@unittest.skip
class TestMe():
  def test_a(self):
    pass

  def test_b(self):
    pass
  ...
```

by adding the annotation `@unittest.skip` on the class instead of each method