# warning: 'X' in try block with 'except ImportError' should also be defined in except block

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to write a wrapper around two similar libraries which would give me a common API to both of them. Example:

```
# file XY.version.py
try:
    import X  # primary library
    __version__ = X.__version__
except ImportError:
    import Y  # fallback library
    __version__ = Y.__y_version__
```

PyCharm shows warning `"'X' in try block with 'except ImportError' should also be defined in except block"`. Is there any simple way to restructure code to get rid of the message? Of course I could do `X = None` at the very beginning or in the `except` block but this feels artificial since I only need to import `X` in order to get the version. Ideally I do not want to keep traces of the import in the namespace. Of course I could theoretically do `del X` at the end of the `try` block but this is something I have not seen anywhere so I assume people do not use it and btw. it does not remove the warning message in PyCharm.

Note: I know this is similar to [Checking module name inside 'except ImportError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35901210/checking-module-name-inside-except-importerror) but I believe this is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something along the lines:

```
# file XY.version.py 
try:
  import X  # primary library
  __version__ = X.__version__ 
except ImportError:
  import Y as X # fallback library
  __version__ = X.__y_version__
```

Then use X everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see any answers that give a solution to this but check this link:
https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/

Gives a clue to whats needed with the list of exceptions and meanings.
So if you want to just get rid of the annoying message then add to the exception like so:

```
try:
    import X  # primary library
    __version__ = X.__version__
except ImportError(X):
    import Y  # fallback library
    __version__ = Y.__y_version__
```

Works for me in a similar example and does not seem to affect the outcome.
I'm using Pycharm 2021.1 CE